# How can I create 3D model of terrain from satellite images using Python and openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, 3d, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

I'm doing my project where I have a two satellite images (I consider not a stereo-pair, but satellite photos of the same terrain but the differ angle/height/satellite etc, and maybe even in jpeg format) and my end goal is to create a 3D model using only those images. How can i reach this? 
I prefer to use Python and openCV for images processing. I think I should start with image rectification and after this build disparity map. If I'm wrong, let me know please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this code is doing what you intend to do:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/stereo_match.py